# What is the maximum value of Easting in UTM coordinates?

Tags: projection, cartography

What is the maximum value of Easting in UTM coordinates?

In many websites I found the answer of maximum value is about **834000** meters, but if you convert some of these coordinates below the value will be much higher than that.

Latitude: 61.44 Longitude: 25.40 --> Converted in UTM: Sector: 35 V  Northing: 414668 Easting: **6812844**

Latitude: -47.04 Longitude: -73.48 --> Converted: Sector: 18 G Northing: 615471 Easting: **4789269**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You are correct about the maximum value, you just have the easting and northing backwards.**

In your first example, the *easting* is 414668 m and the *northing* is 6812844 m. The convention is eastings first. You can think of UTM coordinates as $(x, y)$ pairs, and they are sometimes labelled as such. Here's the conversion offered by [one converter](http://rcn.montana.edu/Resources/Converter.aspx):

[image]

As you say, [eastings are usually less than 834 000 m](https://www.maptools.com/tutorials/utm/details), and more than 160 000 m.

Note than some UTM zones are non-standard widths. Also, you will sometimes see coordinates referenced to some neighbouring zone, which isn't a good idea but is sometimes convenient, so the numbers can be unexpectedly large. Lastly: be aware that in the US you may sometimes come across UTM coordinates in other units, such as feet. Horrible.

Answer (score 1):

The circumference of the Earth at the equator is ~40,075km.
Given that each UTM Zone is 6 degrees spaced in Longitude, there are then 60 UTM Zones around the globe.
Each Zone is thus 40,075/60 or ~668km at the equator (less towards the poles).
The central Easting for each Zone is 500km, therefore the max and min Easting for each Zone is 500+668/2 (834km) and 500-668/2 (166km). These max and min Easting values clearly diminish at higher Lattitudes.